# Converting images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How to convert YUY2 images to RGB images in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

Try this submission on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/fileexchange/):

- [YUY2 to RGB converter](http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26249-yuy2-to-rgb-converter) by [Gabi Teodoru](http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/81108)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But when I had used the following syntax, I got the error as unexpected MATLAB expression. The syntax was,
vid = videoinput('winvideo',camera,vinfo.SupportedFormats{format});
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @Kanchan: The code in the file description is an alternative solution taken from the linked newsgroup post. To use the code in the submission itself, download the submission and look at the `YUY2toRGB` function.